# Create Oracle XMLTYPE from CLOB specifying character set

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I'm trying to create XMLTYPE from CLOB column and specify character set explicitly. I've found there is an overloaded XMLTYPE.createXML function which accepts character set but when I execute passing additional arguments I get an error. Why?

```
SELECT
XMLTYPE.createXML(TO_CLOB ('<node1><node2>the &#180; character</node2></node1>'),NLS_CHARSET_ID('AL32UTF8'),'',1,1)  
from dual;
```

error:

> ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'CREATEXML'

The reason why I bother passing the character set is, CLOB column contains characters which are encoded with different character set than the database character set (which for example doesn't support #180).

Comment: I am looking at the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71959 and I don't see the option you mention. Where did you find that overload? Are you sure it was for Oracle (and not, for example, for Java or who knows what else)?

Comment: Your CLOB is plain ASCII - why do you need to specify any character set?

Comment: Look for csid IN number argument, see docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71959. <node1><node2>... is just an example. createXML will be executed with a column which contain special characters which can't be decoded with database NLS_CHARACTERSET character set.

Comment: Then you must provide a `BLOB` not a `CLOB`. Have a look at [DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600) to convert given CLOB into BLOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason why I bother passing the character set is, CLOB column contains characters which are encoded with different character set than the database character set (which for example doesn't support #180).

This one I don't understand. `#180;` is simple plain ASCII, it should work for any condition.

Simply run

```
SELECT
    XMLTYPE.createXML(TO_CLOB('<node1><node2>the &#180; character</node2></node1>'))
from dual;
```

or even shorter

```
SELECT
    XMLTYPE('<node1><node2>the &#180; character</node2></node1>')
from dual;
```

Now, let's assume your XML contains characters which are not supported by database character set, in this case your XML could be `<node1><node2>the ´ character</node2></node1>` for example.

First of all you cannot store (or use) any character in `CLOB` (or `VARCHAR2`) which is not supported by database character set - **never**! You must use `NCLOB` (or `NVARCHAR2`) which are based on *National Database Character Set* and typically support any Unicode character.

You can specify character set in `XMLTYPE.createXML()`, however then you must provide XML as BLOB. You could do it like this:

```
DECLARE
    xmlString NCLOB := '<node1><node2>the '||NCHR(180)||' character</node2></node1>';
    xmlDoc XMLTYPE;     
    xmlBinary BLOB;

    lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
    dest_offset INTEGER := 1;
    src_offset INTEGER := 1;
    read_offset INTEGER := 1;
    warning INTEGER;

BEGIN

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xmlBinary, TRUE);
    DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB(xmlBinary, xmlString, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, dest_offset, src_offset, 2000, lang_context, warning);
    xmlDoc := XMLTYPE.createXML(xmlBinary, 2000, NULL, 1, 1);
END;
```

2000 is the csid of your national database character set. Use

```
SELECT PARAMETER, VALUE, NLS_CHARSET_ID(VALUE) 
FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
WHERE PARAMETER LIKE '%CHARACTERSET';
```

to get your ID's.

Some notes:

I tried with string `N'<node1><node2>the ´ character</node2></node1>'`, however Oracle replaced `´` immediately with `¿`. I did not manage to enter `´` directly.

Almost all [XML Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions002.htm#SQLRF51185) return `VARCAHR2` values (not `NVARCAHR2`), also most of `XMLTYPE` member functions work with `CLOB` (not `NCLOB`). If you just read and store your XML documents as `XMLTYPE` in your database it should be fine, however as soon you start any operations with these data sooner or later you will hit a conversion error. You should really consider to migrate your database character set, see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) and/or [Oracle Database Migration Assistant for Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71288_01/DUMAG/toc.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `XMLType` function

```
SELECT XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
  ||TO_CLOB ('<node1><node2>the &#180; character</node2></node1>')) myxml
FROM dual;
```