# XML Encoding in XMLTYPE column in Oracle DB

Tags: xml, oracle, character-encoding, oracle12c, toad

I have a table created like this:

```
create table b (data timestamp, value XMLTYPE);
```

I run this script in TOAD 12.6 to store a XML in the table.

```
DECLARE
    lc_Soap         CLOB;
    lc_Request      CLOB;
    px_RequestXML   XMLTYPE
        := XMLTYPE ('<test><test1>ABDDÇJJSõ</test1></test>');
BEGIN
    DELETE b;

    lc_Soap :=
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
               <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                  <s:Header>
                      <h:AxisValues xmlns="urn:/microsoft/multichannelframework/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="urn:/microsoft/multichannelframework/">
                          <User xmlns="">TEST</User>
                      </h:AxisValues>
                  </s:Header>
                  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <substr/>
                  </s:Body>
              </s:Envelope>';

    lc_Request :=
        pkg_utils.replace_clob (lc_Soap,
                                '<substr/>',
                                xml_utils.XMLTypeToClob (px_RequestXML));

    px_RequestXML := XMLTYPE.createXML (lc_Request);

    INSERT INTO b
         VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP, px_RequestXML);

    COMMIT;
END;
```

When I try to see what is in the `VALUE` column I get this encoding `UTF-8`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:AxisValues xmlns="urn:/microsoft/multichannelframework/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="urn:/microsoft/multichannelframework/">
      <User xmlns="">TEST</User>
    </h:AxisValues>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <test>
      <test1>ABDDÃ‡JJSÃµ</test1>
    </test>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But this script was build to run in a different DB user or a in Oracle JOB. And in that cases, the encoding is different:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:AxisValues xmlns="urn:/microsoft/multichannelframework/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="urn:/microsoft/multichannelframework/">
      <User xmlns="">TEST</User>
    </h:AxisValues>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <test>
      <test1>ABDDÇJJSõ</test1>
    </test>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The `NLS_CHARACTERSET` parameter for DB is WE8MSWIN1252.
Why this append? And Who can I always store as UTF-8?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is really a problem as you'd have other issues if you had characters outside the DB character set; but the only way around it using the DB char set for the encoding in an XMLType seems to be [via a BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855518/266304).

Comment: Maybe a [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) to UTF-8

Comment: I found that I can see the UTF-8 encoding when I perform a SELECT statement, but I see the original encoding when, in TOAD, I choose F4 and Data tab

Answer (score 11):

Oracle will use the client characterset to create a `XMLTYPE` from a CLOB or String and completely ignore the encoding in the XML prolog (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adxdb/how-to-use-XML-DB.html#GUID-8C49B304-2E88-4B18-BC7E-A5E11316E5D1)). You may set `encoding="blabla"` and it will work. Oracle honors the encoding in the XML prolog only when you create a XMLTYPE from a BLOB.

The client environment also drives the encoding when reading an `XMLTYPE`. If you want a XML document to be encoded in UTF-8 regardless of the client encoding, you have to retrieve it as BLOB.

Either via `getBlobVal()`

```
SELECT (c2).getBlobVal(nls_charset_id('UTF8')) FROM b;
```

or via `xmlserialize()`

```
SELECT xmlserialize(DOCUMENT c2 AS BLOB ENCODING 'UTF-8') FROM b;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you include non-ASCII characters in a content sent from a client to the DB (eg ABDDÇJJSõ), a conversion may be necessary from the client character set to the DB character set. That can get complicated if the client is incorrect about the character set being used, or the database can't handle the characters. If the content comes from a file, there's also the risk of some other application mis-understanding the character set when processing the file (eg version control)

It is often safer to use encoded versions of any potential problem characters. You can use ASCIISTR to get an unambiguous converted version of the string, and UNISTR to convert it back.

```
select asciistr('Çõ'), unistr('\00C7\00F5') from dual;
```

You can even check the characters are converted as you expect.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c7/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f5/index.htm

If there are no non-ascii characters in the script, you eliminate a lot of potential problems. There may still be issues, but they'll be easier to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks Gary, but my focus here is "why and how he changes the encoding header parameter on the xml content?"